# How can I assign a value to a multivariable function in Mathematica corresponding to only one of the variables?

Tags: functions, variable-definitions, assignment, rule

If I consider a function for example:

`g[x_]:=x^2` and fix `g[x0]=10.0` at a certain point `x0`,

then I know that it uses the definition `x^2` for all values of `x` except at `x=x0`. Now I need something like this for a multivariable function, for example

`F[a_,b_]:=a+b;`

I want to fix the value of `F` at `a=a0`, something like this:

`F[a0,b]=23.01`

such that for any value of the second variable `b` it should return the same fixed value `23.01`.

Instead what I understand is that Mathematica considers the second variable `b` as a fixed point `b=b`, hence `F[a0,b]` gives `23.01` but `F[a0,x0]`, for example, returns `a0+x0` !

How can I have this desired assignment of values to a multivariable function so that I can get something like `F[a0,anything=23.01` ?

Thanks

Comment: use f[a0,b_] instead will do the job.

Comment: @Wjx  Intuitively I tried this yesterday and it didn't work (surely I was exhausted and made a mistake) and now it's working !! Thanks a lot. The answer would be really short, can you please write it down ?